# C# Data in EventHandler

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two functions. One creates a timer, other does action when timer expires. Timer function takes 1 additional argument (int). I need it to be passed to action. Here is the code to explain that:

```cs
 public void CreateTimer(int t)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DoAction(timer, ??, t));
        timer.Interval = 4000;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }
```

As you can see, there is `??` in `EventHandler`, and I have no idea, what to put inside. Here is `DoAction`:

```cs
public void DoAction(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e, int l)
    {
        //some stuff here
    }
```

How can I send `int l`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe a lambda expression to the event where you refer to the local variable.

```
timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => { DoAction(s, e, t); };
```

Comment: Thanks for help, Maarten!

Comment: A further small optimization for readability you can make here is removing the curly braces from the lambda expression; you don't need them if there is only a single statement in the block.

Comment: Thanks, Michd! Now it looks alot better, and less complicated in code.

Comment: @Maarten Less characters for your brain to process, but that add nothing to the meaning of the code. `timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => DoActions(s, e, t);` reads easier, in my opinion.